# 2D Rotated Rectangle Collision

Tags: javascript, algorithm, 2d, collision, detection

I'm trying to test if two rectangle objects, one of which being rotated,  are colliding in JavaScript.

Here's the screen shot of what I'm on about.

[image]

After hours of online research, I'm still wondering what's the best way (algorithm) to detect if the laser-ish lime object is overlapping with the blue square.

I'd appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the separating axis theorem for this. Basically, if 2 convex polygons (e.g. rectangles) do NOT intersect, then there should be at least one line (formed by the edges of one of the polygons extended to infinity) where all the corners from one polygon are on one side of it, and all the corners from the other polygon are on the other side.

You can test which side of a line a point is on using a dot product. One vector should be the normal to the line, and the other vector should be a vector from a point on the line to the point you are testing.

If you specify your rectangle corner vertices with a constant winding order (e.g. always clockwise or always counter clockwise) then you'll know the sign that the dot product should be when the points from the other rectangle are on the side of the line corresponding to the outside of the rectangle.

pseudo-code:

```
function hasSeparatingAxis(a, b)
{
    // test each side of a in turn:
    for(i = 0; i < a.side_count; i++)
    {
        normal_x = a.verts[(i+1)%a.side_count].y - a.verts[i].y;
        normal_y = a.verts[i].x - a.verts[(i+1)%a.side_count].x;

        for(j = 0; j < b.side_count; j++)
        {
            dot_product = ((b.vert[j].x - a.verts[i].x) * normal_x) +
                ((b.vert[j].y - a.verts[i].y) * normal_y);
            if(dot_product <= 0.0) // change sign of test based on winding order
                break;
            if(j == b.side_count-1)
                return true; // all dots were +ve, we found a separating axis
        }
   }
   return false;
}

function intersects(a, b)
{
    return !hasSeparatingAxis(a, b) && !hasSeparatingAxis(b, a);
}
```